# Magento 2 Get shipping and billing address of customer after order placed?

Tags: magento2, order-email, shipping-address, customer-address, billing-address

I am working on custom email template.

So I needed customer Billing and Shipping address in below file.

```
/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml
```

Can any 1 help me to get customer address of placed order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved my problem by following edit in below file:

**/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml**

```
$_order = $block->getOrder();  // get order details
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$formatedAddress = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender‌​\OrderSender');
print‌​_r($formatedAddress-‌​>getFormattedBilling‌​Address($_order)); 
print_r($formatedAddress->getFormattedShippingAddress($_orde‌​r));
```

Comment: Using object manager directly is not recommended.

Comment: `getFormattedShippingAddress` is protected method you cannot access outside.

Comment: You can directly create object for Renderer class. `$formatedAddress = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer');
echo $formatedAddress->format($_order->getShippingAddress(), 'html')`

Comment: i am getting with html tag how to remove it

Answer (score 5):

You can add this piece of code in the file:

```
<?php /** @var $_order \Magento\Sales\Model\Order */ ?>
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php $billingAddress = $_order->getBillingAddress(); ?>
<?php $shippingAddress = $_order->getShippingAddress(); ?>
```

With `$billingAddress` now you can get address
e.g:

```
<?php echo $billingAddress->getStreet() ?>
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the whole address?
Not like getFirstName() or else.

Comment: How can I call formattedBillingAddress() function their as like email templates

Comment: Solved my problem by following : $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$formatedAddress = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender');print_r($formatedAddress->getFormattedBillingAddress($_order));
print_r($formatedAddress->getFormattedShippingAddress($_order));